# Meet of two compact elements need not to be compact.

Tags: compactness, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

I am doing exercises from Universal Algebra by Clifford Bergman.

**Question** (Bergman 2.34.5) Let $a,b$ be compact elements in algebraic lattice $L$. (2) Must $a\wedge b$ be compact?

**My thoughts** I think I found a counterexample on web (see below) but it is rather involved and it seems to me that the point of the exercise is, that there are simpler counter-examples.

*I would like to find some more natural counter-example to $(2)$.*

**Definitions** Let $L$ be a complete lattice

(a) Element $a$ in $L$ is called compact if for every $X\subset L$:

$a\leq \bigvee X \rightarrow (\exists \text{ finite } Z\subset X) ~a\leq \bigvee Z $

(b) $L$ is called algebraic if every element is the join of compact elements.

**"My" counter-example**

Wikipedia lists an example of two compact sets $U,V$ in Hausdorf space $X$ whose intersection is not compact https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#cite_note-17.

I came to the conclusion, that unlike for general closure operator from topology, for this particular topology the closer operator is indeed Agebraic. So the lattice of closed subsets of $X$ is an algebraic lattice and $U,V$ are the desired counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So essentially you have the following lattice:

[image]

where $a$ and $b$ are compact but $a \wedge b$ is not compact.

Notice that you can define a topological space from this lattice as the one whose open sets are, up to isomorphism, the elements of the lattice.
Make $X = \{ u_0, u_1, u_2, \ldots, a, b \}$ and the open sets are
$$\varnothing, U_0, U_1, U_2, \ldots, U, V, W, X,$$
where $U_i = \{ u_0, \ldots, u_i \}$, $U = \bigcup_i U_i, V = U \cup\{a\}$ and $W = U \cup \{b\}$

Comment: Notice, that your topology  (when I understand $u_i$ as $i$ and $u$ as $N$) is contained in the topology  I am referencing. But in this coarser form, I understand lattice-theoretic properties better. So thanks for that!

Comment: @dmk Yes, this topology is different. It's not Hausdorff. This is the [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) of the lattice. (Although is the linked article the open sets are order-filters, not ideals; I think I saw somewhere the definition of Alexandrov topology with order-ideals; anyway it's equivalent.)